# In a ISO8601 date, can a UTC time be represented with +00:00 suffix?

Tags: date, datetime, standards, iso8601

According to ISO 8601, is a timestamp like this valid?:

```
2019-03-06T12:38:51+00:00
```

According to Wikipedia:

> An offset of zero, in addition to having the special representation
>   "Z", can also be stated numerically as "+00:00", "+0000", or "+00".

But in the standard there is mention or example where the offset is zero. It just states the use of the suffix `Z` for UTC times.

Comment: I edited your question, because ISO standards are copyrighted and cannot be pasted here.  The link you gave is to a pirated version of an older draft copy of the non-current standard anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's valid and the important wordage from the standard is actually right there in the screenshot you posted, in section 5.3.4.1:

> It shall be expressed as positive [...] if the local time is ahead of **or equal to** UTC [...]

Comment: Thanks. Are Z and +00:00 equal both in effects and *meaning*? For example, can it be that "Z" means "UTC time" while "+00:00" means "a local time with zero offset to UTC"

Comment: @Victor I'm not an expert on this stuff, what I can tell you is that there are cases in which this can, technically, be different. For instance, the UK uses GMT/UTC in winter and BST (UTC+01:00) in summer. Given a timestamp saying `+00:00`, technically you don't know whether it's British time or UTC. I think a lot of implementations play fast and loose with this kind of thing.

Comment: You are correct - `Z` is explicitly UTC (which applies globally) where `+00:00` means  "the local time offset from UTC is zero".  Thus, they do not have exactly the same meaning, even if they represent the same value.

Comment: While philosophically @MattJohnson is correct (and thanks for the precision), in practice I use `Z` and `+00:00` interchangeably, and I have never seen code that assigns them different semantics (code that accepts only one or only the other is commonplace, though).